# is woman yoga (exercise) in shul ok

Tags: halacha, women, synagogue

If we take the opinion that [yoga is not avoda zorah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/is-practicing-yoga-against-torah)

(I am looking for sources on these questions, I know to ask a LOR)

Can there be a woman's yoga class in a shul (not during davening)?

Would no Sefer Torah in the Aron Hakodesh help?

Doese a mechitza need to be made (and what dimensions) to block the Aron Hakodesh?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think yoga is different from any other non-prayer activity in the Shul? Do you think the gender of the participants mattes?

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not familiar with this subject at all, I am interested in all information, available. Thank you

Comment: @DoubleAA some of the congregants of a shul gave ideas why it may be a problem, and asked me to research this

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([13:1](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2)) summarises the sanctity of a Shul:

> קְדֻשַּׁת בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת וּבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ גְּדוֹלָה מְאֹד, וּמֻזְהָרִים עֲלֵיהֶם לִירֹא מִמִּי שֶׁהוּא שׁוֹכֵן בָּהֶם יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ, כְּדִכְתִיב, וּמִקְדָּשִׁי תִּירָאוּ. וּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת וּבֵית הַמִּדְרָשׁ נִקְרָאִים גַּם כֵּן מִקְדָּשׁ, כְּדִכְתִיב, וָאֱהִי לָהֶם לְמִקְדָּשׁ מְעַט, וְדָרְשֵׁינַן אֵלּוּ בָּתֵּי כְנֵסִיּוֹת וּבָתֵּי מִדְרָשׁוֹת. וְלָכֵן **אָסוּר לְדַבֵּר בָּהֶם דְּבָרִים בְּטֵלִים**. וְאֵין מְחַשְּׁבִין בָּהֶם חֶשְׁבּוֹנוֹת אֶלָּא שֶׁל מִצְוָה. כְּגוֹן קֻפָּה שֶׁל צְדָקָה וְכַדּוֹמֶה. וְנוֹהֲגִין בָּהֶם כָּבוֹד לְכַבְּדָם וּלְרַבְּצָם, וּמַדְלִיקִין בָּהֶם נֵרוֹת לְכָבוֹד. אֵין לְנַשֵּׁק בָּהֶם בָּנָיו הַקְּטַנִּים, שֶׁאֵינוֹ רָאוּי לְהַרְאוֹת שָׁם אַהֲבָה אַחֶרֶת זוּלַת אַהֲבַת הַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ (צ"ח קנ"א). ‏

The sanctity of a shul is very great, as we are commanded to fear the One Who Dwells there - i.e. Hashem Yisborach.

One may not shmooze in a shul, nor may one make calculation (plans, designs, meetings) in them, unless it's Mitzva-related, e.g. for charity.

One honours a shul by keeping it clean and well lit.

One may not kiss [even] little kids in shul, as it's inappropriate to show love for anybody but Hashem, when in shul.

In 14:1 the Kitzur discusses eating in a shul.

> אָסוּר לֶאֱכֹל אוֹ לִשְׁתֹּת אוֹ לִישֹׁן בָּהֶם אֲפִלּוּ שְׁנַת עֲרַאי. וּלְצֹרֶךְ מִצְוָה כְּגוֹן בְּלֵיל יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים מֻתָּר לִישֹׁן, אַךְ יִתְרַחֵק מִן אֲרוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ. וְכֵן לֶאֱכֹל שָׁם לְצֹרֶךְ מִצְוָה, סְעוּדָה שֶׁאֵין בָּהּ שִׁכְרוּת וְלֹא קַלּוּת רֹאשׁ, מֻתָּר. וְכֵן אוֹתָם אֲנָשִׁים שֶׁלּוֹמְדִים שָׁם בִּקְבִיעוּת, מֻתָּרִים לֶאֱכֹל וְלִישֹׁן שָׁם אֲפִלּוּ שְׁנַת קֶבַע, שֶׁלֹּא יִתְבַּטְּלוּ מִלִּמּוּדָם (סִימָן קנ"א תרי"ט וביו"ד סִימָן רמ"ו).  ‏

It's forbidden to eat, drink, sleep and even nap in a shul. For the purpose of a Mitzva - like on Yom Kippour night, one should nap as far away from the Aaron Hakodesh as possible.

One does not eat in shul unless it's a Seudat Mitzva, and there's no alcohol served and no levity.

Similarly, those who learn all day, may eat and sleep in shul, so as not to waste time.

---

That's the basics. If anybody behaves otherwise, they need to bring a source for their actions. (Obviously exercising in shul would be absolutely forbidden.)

Comment: will a mehitza help

Comment: I don't see anywhere that these laws are different in the women's gallery - and that is behind a Mechitza.

Comment: You don't memtiom shuld built al tenai, such as all shuls in the diaspora. As such this is a poor answer

Comment: @DoubleAA - the Kitzur talks only about shuls built in the diaspora; yet he doesn't seem to differentiate. See the kesef Mishne - Rambam הלכות תפילה וברכת כהנים Ch 11:7 who says:  כסף משנה  ואין מחשבין בהם חשבונות וכו'. שם אמר רב אסי בתי כנסיות של בבל על תנאי עשויים כלומר על מנת שישתמשו בהם ואף ע''פ כן אין נוהגים בהם קלות ראש ומאי ניהו חשבונות, ומפרש רבינו דהיינו דוקא חשבון של רשות ודבר פשוט הוא. QED.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Shulchan Aruch - Orach Chaim - סימן קנא - דיני קדשת בית הכנסת also says יא אִם בִּשְׁעַת בִּנְיַן בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת  הִתְנוּ עָלָיו לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בּוֹ, מֻתָּר לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בּוֹ  בְּחֻרְבָּנוֹ; אֲבָל בְּיִשּׁוּבוֹ, לָא מְהָנֵי תְּנָאָה.... בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים, בְּבָתֵּי כְּנֵסִיּוֹת  שֶׁבְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ, אֲבָל בְּבָתֵּי כְּנֵסִיּוֹת שֶׁבְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל, לָא מְהָנֵי שׁוּם תְּנַאי.