# Is tai chi considered avodah zara?

Tags: avodah-zarah

Is tai chi considered avodah zara? It might have some roots in buddhism and/or taoism, but is it still avodah zara if I am only interested in the physical benefits of tai chi?

I checked out the three links below, and it seems to me that nobody knows for sure tai chi's origins, and in addition the modern form of tai chi is, for the most part, a secularized phyiscal sport.

https://www.quora.com/Is-tai-chi-part-of-buddhism

https://www.reddit.com/r/Buddhism/comments/35e8ci/buddhism_tai_chi/

Comment: Do a google search of Rabbi Gustman Locks try and contact him,this is(was) his area of expertise.

Comment: I googled "Rabbi Gustman Locks" but nothing of value came up. Are you sure you spelt it right?

Comment: spelt it wromg,its gutman locks

Comment: I'll ask my Rabbi, see what he says.

Comment: Is this the Gutman Locks you were referring to?https://www.facebook.com/gutman.locks

Comment: yes thats him,very fascinating individual,very knowledgeable with these things

Comment: Read this,hope its helpful...http://www.mpaths.com/2010/02/chi-kung-tai-chi-and-idolatry.html?m=1

Comment: @sam - Rabbi Gutman Locks is the man to go to for these kinds of things.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8713

Comment: Do the exercises/fighting forms/ceremonies associated with it make appeals to the foreign gods?  Or is it just based on tradition that mortal teachers revered in the East established the basics? Or some combination of the two?

Comment: Based on what @Gary asked, how would tai chi be different from becoming a Mason? It also has rites and practices.

Comment: @DanF-  the Wiki page on it makes the relationships seem kind of complex.  It's going to take me a while to puzzle it out - but my first impression is that it has philosophical ties to Taoism, but isn't a part of it. Maybe there's a martial arts/Eastern Religion expert around here that can explain it in easily digestible terms.

Comment: here's rabbi zev leff on "Reiki" http://www.rabbileff.net/shiurim/answers/0250-0499/0315.mp3 and http://www.rabbileff.net/shiurim/answers/1750-1999/1779.mp3

Comment: I heard a shiur once from Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz where he said he cannot find a hetter to allow this, but at the same time he doesn't go around saying it is assur. If you are interested, try to contact him.

Comment: One might also look at [Taiji (philosophy) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiji_(philosophy)), which while not a religion does contain spiritual elements.  Then determine whether the physical exercise is taught with or without this semi-religious aspect.  ("T'ai Chi" and "Tàijí" are the same word, but using different Chinese/Roman transliteration.)

Answer (score 2):

Rabb Gutman Locks who he himself studied in India under gurus, eventually becoming a guru himself with many followers discusses the dangers of these practices.

His story :
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/959313/jewish/The-Guru-Jew.htm

From Mystical Paths  - Rabbi Gutman Locks:

Chi Kung and Tai Chi are more than simple movement meditation techniques. For instance, Tai Chi is almost always associated with Taoism. Taoism is an Eastern religion, which from its earliest roots writes of "ghosts, and deities, and wives of deities…immortals [i] "and of 'god.'" [ii] Taoism is a "reinterpretation of an ancient unnamed tradition of nature worship, divination[iii], and magic." [iv]

Can these practices be taught in a kosher way?

Even if your student only touches his toes and dances, if you tell him that he is practicing Chi Kung, or Tai Chi - or any other practice that is rooted in a religion other than the Torah - you are endangering his soul.

Beside the immediate spiritual intrusion that automatically occurs from practicing these aspects of foreign religions, students will often want to learn more about their new exercise system. They then buy books, visit Web sites, and put pictures on their walls. Then, when they move to another town, they find an "authentic" Oriental teacher. The result is that that Jewish student will soon believe in the spiritual teachings that accompany the exercises. Those names and roots are taken from Buddhism, and the Tao, and on and on.

Again, and to reiterate most clearly, any practice that is entirely physical with absolutely no association with other religions is assumed to be perfectly alright. However, the minute you include even a slight reference or association to those other religions, you are endangering your spiritual life.

Remember, there are many perfectly fine, non-spiritual systems available. There is no reason to look to the ways of the East.

Comment: Looking to clarify: is this the technical issur of chukas akum, or just a slippery slope argument?

Comment: He is saying that if you get involved then it's very difficult to ignore the origins of it,and then when practicing using their terminology and philosophy is already a real issue

Comment: Sounds like only slippery slope. Although, to me, the practice sounds like a perfect example of chukas akum. I wonder how objective the practical benefits are. Maybe any exercise would do just as good? If so, this is exactly chukas akum.

Comment: That's not convincing without saying HOW tai-chi is associated with Taoism.

Answer (score 0):

Tai chi is not a form of worship and cannot in any way be categorized as such. Therefore your problem with the Avodah Zarah aspect is simply solved.

However, there is a prohibition of 
 וּבְחֻקֹּתֵיהֶם לֹא תֵלֵכוּ
which includes all kinds of rituals the pagans practice. But this does not include rituals (chukim) that people do for a good reason, the rituals are only prohibited if they have no rhyme or reason (see Tos. Avodh zara 11b. see also Ran). In this case, even if tai chi is an old pagan ritual, you want the benefits of tai chi and therefore should be permitted.

The problem of Nichush should not apply here, since the one practicing it is deriving physical benefits from it and is permitted in such a case (even if some of the other  benefits might be categorized as Nichush).

Comment: "Tai chi is not a form of worship and cannot in any way be categorized as such." How do you know this??

Comment: Even if it was at one point a form of worship, it is not anymore viewed by the majority as such. It is categorized as martial arts in wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_chi). In such a case the practice cannot be categorized as Avodah zara, at most it may be classified as Chukei A"z....which i already dealt with in the second paragraph.

Comment: How do you know that? And why does Wikipedia matter? And why does how it's viewed by a majority of people matter?

Comment: if he is not using it as a form of worship, and the majority does not view it that way, why would you say that it is Avodah zara? if you want to say otherwise the onus proof is on you!

Comment: No, you posted an answer so the onus is on you!

Comment: "You want the benefits so it should be permitted." Someone doing outright avoda zara  also wants the benefits. There only heter for chukas akum is direct practical benefits, not "this feels right."

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Shmuel Eliyahu says it's [permitted](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%98%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A6%D7%99/).

Also Grand-master [Nir Malchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nir_Malhi) who is an observant Jew, [says](https://www.makorrishon.co.il/nrg/online/55/ART2/843/534.html) that a leading Rabbi told him not to close his dojo.