# Yoga with a Buddha idol in the same room?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Is it allowed to participate a yoga class while a Buddha idol is placed in the room owned by the yoga studio? Even if one has no intention of praying to the idol?

Comment: More generally: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8713

Comment: By the way, the state of NY registers yoga gyms as a Buddhist religious center even if the business is not related to the religion at all. Interesting, huh?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit in why specifically yoga? Is that a way of serving the idol? If so, I can quote you a Gemara in AZ offhand that would forbid it.

Comment: @DonielF I can do you one better, I can quote you one of the Big 10 that would say it's forbidden ;)

Comment: Yoga is based on Hindu practices, although what we see is really an American invention. Hinduism is generally 'avodah zara though.

Comment: Whose idol is it?

Comment: @Salmononius2 Of course if it's Avodah Zarah it would fall under at least one of the Big 10. The Gemara I'm referring to (AZ 50b-51a) discusses what counts as such; namely, ways normally used to serve them or to serve HaShem. If yoga is a way of serving this deity, that Gemara clearly states that it is Avodah Zarah.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt There is a difference between Hinduism and Buddhism. Should the OP be edited to discuss a Hindu idol?

Comment: @DonielF, possibly, although I'm not sure whether it would impact the halacha per se.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Based on the Gemara I quoted above it would. It's a way of serving Hindu gods, not Buddhist ones. Thus, not AZ. No different than defecating on any idol besides Pe'or.

Comment: @DonielF, if the studio leader believes that yoga serves Buddhism, then it would be 'a"z.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I agree one hundred percent. That would change things a lot if the instructor actually thought this way.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I'll have to check the mefarshim to that Gemara, but I'm not sure that intent is enough.

Comment: Yoga itself is avoda zara and is from hinduism