# Is doing a Haka dance potentially an issue of Avodah Zarah?

Tags: avodah-zarah

The Maori tribes have an interesting custom of performing a Hakah dance, (which you can find on YouTube) would doing one violate laws against Avodah Zarah?

Comment: Is a haka related to worship? I thought it developed from tribal warriors.

Comment: @rosends I've read that it is a ritualized reenactment of the triumph of their sun god, associated with the solstice, or that it is a ritualized channeling of the power of their war god. Either way, it is almost certainly rooted in their pagan mythology.

Comment: @TheThinkingYid, I don't know if it has been specifically addressed, but I would expect the analysis to be similar to that of yoga: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/is-practicing-yoga-against-torah

Comment: More likely Derekh Emori / Chuqas haAkum. (Torah and rabbinic idioms respectively for [following] the ways of the Emorites [or other non-Jewish locals] / Rules of the Idolaters. Same prohibition, two names.) In order for it to be AZ, today's haka dancers would have to still be doing the dance for worship. Once the practice is just cultural, it is still prohibited, but under this other and not as severe commandment. (This is the discussion around celebrating Halloween today, when the original Celtic motivations are ancient history.)